# Invalid operand compiler error involving std::equal_range

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++14

For an implementation of an interval map using the following template

```
template<class K, class V>
intervalMap{
public:
intervalMap(V const&);
public:
void assign(K const&, K const&, V const&);
private:
std::map<K,V>m_map;
};
```

And the following code segment inside the member function `assign()`:

```
template<class K, class V> void intervalMap::assign(
                                             K const& keyBegin, 
                                             K const& keyEnd,
                                             V const& val
                                            ){

            auto begin = m_map.find(keyBegin);
            auto end = m_map.find(keyEnd);

            auto p = std::equal_range(begin,end,val);

}
```

and the following instantiation in main()

```
intervalMap<unsigned int, char> iMap('A');
iMap.assign(1,2,'A');
```

The following compilation error results:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
In file included from ./code.hpp:4:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/
include/c++/v1/map:442:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr
/include/c++/v1/__tree:18:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/
c++/v1/algorithm:701:71: 
error: invalid operands to binary expression 
('const std::__1::pair<const unsigned int, char>' and 'int')
    bool operator()(const _T1& __x, const _T2& __y) 
const {return __x < __y;}
              ~~~ ^ ~~~
```

The error pertains to the following source code segment (as highlighted in the error log):

```
./code.hpp:120:18: note: in instantiation of function 
template specialization 'std::__1::equal_range
<std::__1::__map_iterator
<std::__1::__tree_iterator
<std::__1::__value_type
<unsigned int, char>, 
std::__1::__tree_node
<std::__1::__value_type
<unsigned int, char>, 
void *> *, long> >, 
char>' 
requested here
        auto p = equal_range(begin,end,val);
                 ^
./code.hpp:205:10: note: 
in instantiation of member function 
'interval_map<unsigned int, char>::assign' 
requested here
    iMap.assign(1,2,'A');
```

Appreciate suggestions.

Comment: `std::map m_map;` This line ain't valid.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo...will edit my original post

Comment: What type do you think you get when you dereference `begin` or `end`? Does that explain the error message?

Comment: @Praetorian dereferencing begin or end should fetch a std::pair<> corresponding to the particular key index of the map. But why should this error occur as I am invoking std::equal_range() with the correct arguments?

Comment: Because `equal_range` will then attempt to compare `pair<const K, V>` and `char`. You need to use the overload that takes a custom comparator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error is due to comparing std::pair and template variable denoted by V, in this case char. To avoid this you can use costume predicate as below.

```
template<class K, class V>
class intervalMap{
public:
intervalMap(V  val)
{
   v = val;
}
public:
void assign(K const a, const K  b,  const V c);

private:
V v;
std::map<K,V> m_map;

};
template<class K, class V>
struct comp
{
    bool operator()(std::pair<K, V> a, V b)
    {
        return a.second < b;
    }
    bool operator()(V a, std::pair<K, V> b)
    {
        return a < b.second;
    }
};

template<class K, class V>
void intervalMap<K, V>::assign(const K  keyBegin, const K  keyEnd, const V  
val)
{
    auto begin = m_map.find(keyBegin);
    auto end = m_map.find(keyEnd);


    auto p = std::equal_range(begin, end, val,comp< K,  V>());
}
```