# Type conversion operators related to Compare for std::equal_range()

Tags: c++, type-conversion, compare, operator-overloading, c++14

This question is a follow-up on

[Invalid operand compiler error involving std::equal_range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48896994/invalid-operand-compiler-error-involving-stdequal-range)

In order to use the overloaded version of std::equal_range() taking the address of the binary comparison predicate as the fourth argument, it is also required to provide conversion operators that enable conversion between the involved types according to

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range

To do this type conversion, within the context of the problem described in the original question (see link at the beginning), conversion operators need to be provided that could convert between `V const&` and `std::pair<K const&, V const&>`, where K and V are the template arguments. My understanding is that a conversion operator can only be defined within the scope of a class/template class and the only possibility is to convert from the class/template class to a required type.
In the light of this restriction, is there a way that the conversion operators could be defined to address the prerequisite for invoking the overloaded version of std::equal_range(), as intended within the scope of the discussion presented in the original question (see link at the beginning)?

Comment: That description is not really correct for `std::equal_range`. What we meant to say is that the comparator needs to be callable both ways.

Comment: `std::equal_range` requires that the range be sorted. Are you sure your map happens to be sorted by value, as well as by key? That would be unusual.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik In my code, I work with the given that the keys are sorted in ascending order by default in std::map. Not sure whether sorting of values is needed, as I presume that it is not going to make any difference towards how fast a particular element could be retrieved. Since there is a definite bound within which insertion has to happen, I guess the position returned in p.first by equal_range() could be a good starting point.

Comment: You are trying to find an equal range of values, are you not? You pass a value of type `V`, not `K`, as the third parameter to `equal_range`. This doesn't make any sense unless values are sorted. What exactly are you trying to achieve with that `equal_range` call? I suspect you might misunderstand what it does.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Since I would get the first position that Is equal to val anyway if there is one within the range provided to equal_range(), I can work with that. At this point, all I am focusing on is to insert value (even the same value) into the interval map, as long as no two values repeat in adjacent positions. However, I also intend to implement later an efficient sorting algorithm to sort the values of the map, after each insertion.

Comment: Your description makes no sense whatsoever. What do you mean by "insert value"? You don't insert a value into a `std::map` - you insert `{key, value}` pair, and it will be automatically positioned among existing entries according to the order of keys, not values. What do you mean by "adjacent positions"? Adjacent in what ordering, exactly? You can't sort `std::map` by any order other than the order of keys - which, again, it maintains automatically.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik My code has been written to insert a value (any random value) based on the std::pair<first,second> returned by std::equal_range(). If the value of first is not equal to the argument last to std::equal_range(), I insert the value in the next key slot. But if first != last and second == last, I insert the value in a free key slot after the value of first and before last. If that cannot be done (no free key slot in the range [first, last), I throw an exception. 
Everything hinges on the value returned in first by std::equal() and I am now debugging some issue with this.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand. Anyway, you are likely looking for `std::find_if`, not `std::equal_range`, when searching for a pair in the range with a given value. As in: `auto p = std::find_if(begin, end, [&val](const std::pair<const K, V>& elem) { return elem.second == val });`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I was not aware of that standard library function. Thanks for point it out.